# Insert Multiple Values into Multiple different cells

Tags: excel, vba, performance, cell

I have the below code which updates the relevant cell with the relevant value. Even though there is only 11, I was wondering if there is a much better way, for the purpose of helping to speed up the code & also incase there is ever a need to update 000's of cells.

```
Range("E1").Value = "Export Date"
Range("G1").Value = "Amended Start Date"
Range("H1").Value = "Ticket Age (Working Days)"
Range("J1").Value = "Overdue (1=Yes, 0=No)"
Range("U1").Value = "TicketEntity1"
Range("V1").Value = "TicketEntity2"
Range("W1").Value = "TicketEntity3"
Range("X1").Value = "TicketEntity4"
Range("Y1").Value = "TicketEntity5"
Range("Z1").Value = "TicketEntity6"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub Test()

Dim CurrentColumn As Long
Dim i As Long

CurrentColumn = 20

With wsTest
    For i = 1 To 5 '<= Use the correct number according your requirements
        .Cells(1, CurrentColumn + 1).Value = "TicketEntity" & i
        CurrentColumn = CurrentColumn + 1
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tighten it up with arrays to cover the contiguous cells.

```
Range("E1").Value = "Export Date"
Range("G1:H1").Value = array("Amended Start Date","Ticket Age (Working Days)")
Range("J1").Value = "Overdue (1=Yes, 0=No)"
Range("U1:Z1").Value = array("TicketEntity1","TicketEntity2","TicketEntity3", _
                             "TicketEntity4","TicketEntity5","TicketEntity6")
```

The *TicketEntryx* series could also be looped with the increment used as a suffix identifier.